# Space between tr's, with tr's as contiguous blocks

Tags: css, html-table, tablerow

I want to format a table to show as rows, with each row being a contiguous box, and with space between the rows. Example:

```
<table>
<tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>24</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jack</td><td>Foo</td><td>34</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>Beam</td><td>102</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I want should look something like the following:

[image]

I have achieved the above by making additional tr-rows between the data:

```
<style>
body { background-color: #aaaaff; } 
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
.space_tr { height: 1px; }
.info_tr { background-color: grey; }
.info_tr td { padding: 5 20 5 20px; }
</style>
<table>
<tr class='info_tr'><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>24</td></tr>
<tr class='space_tr'><td colspan='3'></td></tr>
<tr class='info_tr'><td>Jack</td><td>Foo</td><td>34</td></tr>
<tr class='space_tr'><td colspan='3'></td></tr>
<tr class='info_tr'><td>Jim</td><td>Beam</td><td>216</td></tr>
</table>
```

But I want to know if I can achieve this formatting with just CSS, i.e. without changing anything in the html that I wrote in the top.

EDIT:

Adam Kiss suggested using a bottom-border with same color as the background. This works in my current case, but as he points out, this will not work when having background which is not just a same-color surface.

For completeness: Can the above be achieved while maintaining transparency of the spacing gaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your situation is as your picture suggests, meaning you have full color background, following should be absolutely sufficient:

```
td { padding: 5px 20px; background: #666; border-bottom: 3px solid #backgroundColor; }
```

:)

Just noticed your update: I would either use some <span> (or different tag) inside <td> or play with margins on <td>s, although I don't think that that would work :)

Comment: Nice. I did not know that you could specify borders on just one side.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `border-bottom: 2px solid #aaaaff;` to your `tr`s, where `#aaaaff` is your body's background-color and `2px` is the space between the rows.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHdgz/

Comment: I believe, that you can not specify borders on a tr-element, right?

Comment: Try and add `<style> tr { border: 1px black solid; } </style>` to my first bit of css-less html. It has no effect.

Comment: Wtf. When I open your link, the borders are shown. But when I insert that css line in to an html file locally on my computer, it has no effect ??? I'm using Firefox 3.6

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
    table { border-collapse: collapse; border:solid 10px #aaaaff; background-color:#aaaaff;}
    .space_tr { height: 1px; }
    .info_tr { background-color: grey; }
    .info_tr td { padding: 5 20 5 20px; }
    </style>
    <table>
    <tr class='info_tr'><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>24</td></tr>
    <tr class='space_tr'><td colspan='3'></td></tr>
    <tr class='info_tr'><td>Jack</td><td>Foo</td><td>34</td></tr>
    <tr class='space_tr'><td colspan='3'></td></tr>
    <tr class='info_tr'><td>Jim</td><td>Beam</td><td>216</td></tr>
    </table>
```

try this..... it can b work

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want to achieve the layout, _without_ having intermediate rows just for spacing.