# Newbie: How to have a row background in my case?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple table:

```
<table border="1" class="my-table">
  <tr class="head">
       <th>head-1</th>
       <th>head-2</th>
       <th>head-3</th>
       <th>head-4</th>
       <th>head-5</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <div class="row-data">
           <td>data-1</td>
           <td>data-2</td>
           <td>data-3</td>
           <td>data-4</td>
           <td>data-5</td>
      </div>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

As you saw above, the **second row** `<tr>` contains a `<div>` which then contains `<td>`s , the reason why I did this is that **I want to have a row background which has** `border-radius` **css feature for each row** instead of for each column(`<td>`)

(I konw if I put `<div>` inside `<td>`, the following **css** will take effect, but that's **not** what I want [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/EWPVc/25/) , it is a column based border-radius background, however I need a row based one.)

my **css**:

```
.row-data{
    background-color:#ececec;
    border-radius:10px;
   -webkit-border-radius:10px;
   -moz-border-radius:10px;
}
```

But it does not work in this way to have a row`<tr>` based **border-radius** css feature, how to get rid of it? 
**You can run my code** on [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EWPVc/17/)

Comment: a `div` as child of `tr` is not valid html

Comment: @Sotiris, I agree with you, I made that just to emphasis what I want to achieve, that's a row based background has the border-radius, not a column <td> based one.

Comment: Rob is right. 
Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407371/webkit-and-moz-border-radius-does-not-work-on-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this may be that you want http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/EWPVc/24/

```
td{
    background-color:red;
}
td:first-child{
    border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
   -moz-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
}
td:last-child{
     border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    -moz-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
 }
```

Comment: @ sandeep, yes, this is working, by the way, how should I add space between rows I mean between <tr>?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856114/css-space-between-trs-with-trs-as-contiguous-blocks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making a new div for it just add the class to the row: `<tr class="row-data">`

Comment: No, I tried, it does not work, I mean the background of the row does not have border-radius which is my most concerned feature in this post.

Comment: I really do not understand why people continue voting this answer useful, this answer does not work, I tried it before I post the question, see here http://jsfiddle.net/EWPVc/20/ , there is no border-radius on the row background

Comment: @ Rob, you can't say the border-radius not work, it works, for example if I put the div inside <td>, check here http://jsfiddle.net/EWPVc/25/ , if you read my question carefully, you will understand what I want to achieve.

Comment: @ Rob, are you using Opera browser, because the css for border radius won't work on Opera only, other browsers should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

border-radius can apply on table, but not the row.
Check out this demo of border-radius for table: http://vamin.net/examples/rounded_tables.html